# IE 10 Javascript debugger won't step through script

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, debugging

I've been using IE 8, then IE 9 to debug Javascript.
I go to tools \ advanced options \ and turn off "DISABLE SCRIPT DEBUG"
I then put a malformed alert command in the html page and open the html file in IE.  It sees the bad alert command and starts the debugger.  I can then step through each line of script and watch variables changing values.

We have recently upgraded to IE 10 and I've not been able to get this function yet.  It opens up in the debugger just like previous versions. But when I attempt to step through the script it acts like its just instantly moved to the end and the local variables disappear.  ANyone know what I have to do to get IE 10 debugger to actually step into the script?
Thanks!!

Comment: this may not help you much but I highly recomment you to use Chrome or Firefox for a good web debugger.